# What's the probability of him being in the last gym?

Tags: probability

> Bob really likes to go to the gym, so he spends $A$ hours at the gym every day. There are $B$ gyms in the city, and he has the same probability of being in each of them. We've checked $B-1$ gyms, and he was not there. What's the probability of him being in the last gym?

**My work:** At a given time, he is at the gym with $\frac{A}{24}$ probability. But there are $B$ gyms, so he is at a given gym with $\frac{A}{24B}$ probability, so the answer is $\frac{A}{24B}$.

But I think it's the wrong answer because I was told that it's not an easy exercise. Did I miss out something?

Comment: Sanity check: Suppose $A=24$, so Bob is always at the gym.  Now what is the answer?  Does it agree with your formula?

Comment: @Slade Only for the $B=1$ case. What did I miss out?

Comment: You are not using some of the information: "We've checked $B-1$ gyms."  How does this affect the probabilities?

Comment: I would start by trying to solve the $B=2$ case.

Comment: @Slade Is it $\frac{\frac{A}{2*24}}{1-\frac{A}{2*24}}=\frac{A}{48-A}$?

Comment: That is indeed correct for the case $B=2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $i=1,2,\dots,B$ let $E_i$ be the event that Bob is at gym $i$ and let $F$ be the event that Bob is not at any gym.

To be found is then $P(E_1\mid E_2^{\complement}\cap\cdots\cap E_B^{\complement})=P(E_1\mid E_1\cup F)$ and:$$P(E_1\mid E_1\cup F)=\frac{P(E_1)}{P(E_1\cup F)}=\frac{P(E_1)}{P(E_1)+P(F)}=\frac{\frac{A}{24B}}{\frac{A}{24B}+(1-\frac{A}{24})}=\frac{A}{A+B(24-A)}$$

Comment: Thanks, I've done it a bit different way, but I've got the same result.